# Spark 1.6.0 DataFrame selfjoin issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to perform selfjoin using DataFrame Scala API.
Here are my code snippets; 
Can you please tell me what's wrong with the first solution?

val    df= sqlc.read.json("empMgr.json");

**empMgr.json**

{"ID":101,"ename":"Peter","sal":24.24,"dept":"11","country":"US","doj":"1/12/2017","mgr":201}
{"ID":201,"ename":"John","sal":1300,"dept":"232","country":"IN","doj":"4/22/2016","mgr":111}
{"ID":301,"ename":"Sam","dept":"22","country":"KR","doj":"5/22/2015","mgr":201}

```
// 1. following is not working
var df_right=df; 
df.join(df_right, df("mgr") === df_right("ID")).show()
df.join(df, df("mgr") === df("ID")).show()

/*
 * Output:
 * +---+-------+----+---+-----+---+---+---+-------+----+---+-----+---+---+
    | ID|country|dept|doj|ename|mgr|sal| ID|country|dept|doj|ename|mgr|sal|
    +---+-------+----+---+-----+---+---+---+-------+----+---+-----+---+---+
    +---+-------+----+---+-----+---+---+---+-------+----+---+-----+---+---+
 * */


//2. following works fine
df_right= sqlc.read.json("file:///opt/data/empMgr.json");  
df.join(df_right, df("mgr") === df_right("ID")).show()

/*
 *Output:
 * +---+-------+----+---------+-----+---+-----+---+-------+----+---------+-----+---+------+
    | ID|country|dept|      doj|ename|mgr|  sal| ID|country|dept|      doj|ename|mgr|   sal|
    +---+-------+----+---------+-----+---+-----+---+-------+----+---------+-----+---+------+
    |101|     US|  11|1/12/2017|Peter|201|24.24|201|     IN| 232|4/22/2016| John|111|1300.0|
    |301|     KR|  22|5/22/2015|  Sam|201| null|201|     IN| 232|4/22/2016| John|111|1300.0|
    +---+-------+----+---------+-----+---+-----+---+-------+----+---------+-----+---+------+ 
 * */


//3. following works fine
df.registerTempTable("empMgr")
sqlc.sql("select b.ename, a.ename as mgr,b.mgr from empMgr a join empMgr b on a.ID=b.mgr").show();

/*
 * output
 * +-----+----+---+
  |ename| mgr|mgr|
  +-----+----+---+
  |Peter|John|201|
  |  Sam|John|201|
  +-----+----+---+
 * */
```

Comment: what is your question? Am I mistaken or there is a extra line in point 1 that is not supposed to be there? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Dataframe's `as()` method to remove ambiguity when referencing similar names.

```
df.as("a").join(df.as("b"), $"a.mgr" === $"b.ID").show

+---+-------+----+---------+-----+---+-----+---+-------+----+---------+-----+---+------+
| ID|country|dept|      doj|ename|mgr|  sal| ID|country|dept|      doj|ename|mgr|   sal|
+---+-------+----+---------+-----+---+-----+---+-------+----+---------+-----+---+------+
|101|     US|  11|1/12/2017|Peter|201|24.24|201|     IN| 232|4/22/2016| John|111|1300.0|
|301|     KR|  22|5/22/2015|  Sam|201| null|201|     IN| 232|4/22/2016| John|111|1300.0|
+---+-------+----+---------+-----+---+-----+---+-------+----+---------+-----+---+------+
```

Comment: I could not test this as I am getting below error. 
**'value $ is not a member of StringContext'  **

Here are my maven dependencies
`
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.0</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>`

Comment: Try importing the implicits and see if that fixes it: `import sqlContext.implicits._`

Comment: Thanks, It worked. Up voted.
1. Can you also tell me issue with solution#1? is it in-correct syntax?
2.Can someone also provide me the Java fix?